# What is this error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on chapter 11 of Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial and I got this error message trying to show the user's microposts while trying to build a Twitter clone.  What model name is it referring to when it says "Undefined method  'model_name' for NilClass:Class?

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:       </h1>
8:     <% unless @user.microposts.empty? %>
9:         <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
10:           <%= render @microposts %>
11:         </table>
12:         <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
13:       <% end %>
```

*Edit* In the action I set `@microposts`:

```
@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

*Edit*Controller code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
before_filter :admin_user, :only => :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

   def edit

    @title = "Edit user"
   end

   def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

     def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

     def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

Comment: Is there a @microposts variable, or is it @user.microposts?

Comment: In users controller, we created a microposts variable using user.microposts. See update at bottom of OP. Note, out of curisoity, I changeed microposts to user.microposts in this view and the error message now said: "The users variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?"

Comment: Please post the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the full source code, but you might be able to track down the problem by comparing your source to the [reference code at GitHub](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app).